# Cognito SAML integration with Google workspace and Microsoft AD redirects to Cognito Hosted UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, saml-2.0, google-workspace

I setup SAML integration with Google workspace and Microsoft AD for my company users a month ago. We have over 500 users who have successfully logged in except for a couple of users, everytime they try to login they are redirected to Cognito hosted UI for login which doesn't show any errors. The request is not redirected to the callback URL I have specified in my app client.

**P.S: this happens to 1 of my Google users, and 1 of my Microsoft users.**

I tried checking the identities attribute for the users, the issuer is actually updated which means that they successfully logged in via their email.

I checked the pre-token generation lambda logs to check if an error occurs, but it seems to be working fine.

I also checked the callback URL in their requests and they seem to be fine.

I checked the logs in Google Admin Audit and investigation to check for any requests that have failed. They all have a success status.